# Xsd element dependency based on collection values

Tags: xml, xsd, dependencies

I have a collection defined in my XSD where it is possible to set an attribute to a specific mime-type. One of the mime-types is for example: application/pdf.

Is it possible in XSD to create a dependency, relation or something similar when in the collection one of the elements contains a application/pdf attribute that an another element should be required?

For example:

```
<collection>
   <item mime-type="application/pdf" />
   <item mime-type="image/jpeg" />
</collection>
```

In this collection there is one 'application/pdf' element. The XSD should require that an another element should be filled in (but it is not required when the collection does not contain any application/pdf element).

For example:

```
<pdfdetails>
   <somedetails></somedetails>
</pdfdetails>
```

Answer (score 0):

Such dependencies can be defined using assertions in XSD 1.1. There's no way of doing it in XSD 1.0. XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Saxon, Xerces, and (since last week) Altova.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Kay has already pointed out, this is easily done in XSD 1.1 using assertions.

Other techniques include:

- conditional type assignment (also XSD 1.1)
- assertions in Schematron (no particular advantage for this case over XSD 1.1 assertions, but may be worth looking into if you cannot deploy an XSD 1.1 implementation but can deploy a Schematron validator)
- refactoring the XML structure to put the MIME-type information into an element name instead of an attribute value, then using normal content-model rules to require the added information (this requires that the additional information either be embedded in the MIME-type element or be somewhere nearby, so a content-model can be constructed to require it conditionally)
- for this particular case, it might be possible to do something clever with referential integrity constraints